# CodeIgniter deployment weird issue with urls

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I've just finished my CI's project and I've uploaded it through FTP to an external server. The thing is that the urls stuff works perfectly on localhost but not in the external server, altough the urls work if I put index.php on the URI.

Example: www.page.com/index.php/shop (works), www.page.com/shop (doesn't work)

I've made my research and all the answers I've found doesn't seem to fit well on my case. I'm working on Linux that use Apache2. I've made these changes:

1-/var/www/dev.example.com (Apache2):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
<Directory /var/www/dev.example.com>
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

2-Config.php(CI):

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/dev.example.com';
```

3-htaccess(CI):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

4-index.php(CI):

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production')
```

What am I missing? Excuse me for my bad english.

EDIT:

I think the problem is that the .htaccess file it's not been called for some reason, so for many changes I make to the file the result will be the same. How can I see if the file it's being used?

Comment: If the main page is working but none of the others, your settings above are correct, but your routes are missing/wrong/incorrect.  Look at your `routes.php` file within the `config` folder.

Comment: I've just have one route in there that calls my main controller: 
    $route['default_controller'] = 'inicio';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solucion. A file named 000-default under /etc/apache2/sites-enabled was causing the troubles. I had something like:

```
<Directory /var/www/ > 
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride None
...
</Directory>
```

So I just changed it to:

```
<Directory /var/www/ > 
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
...
</Directory>
```

And that after a sudo apache2 restart fix my problem. So basically this file was overriding my VHost file.

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

```
$root = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .=  str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

$config['base_url'] = $root;
```

try changing your base url to this.hope it works

i hope your htacess look something like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And uri_protocol in your config file look like this 
    $config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';

Comment: I think that it's not even getting my htaccess because of I put some garbage into the file and I still get the 404 error... It may give me another error doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Well I have this .htaccess running on my CI application in the server. Why not give this a try?

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: doesn't work mate... I guess it's a kind of a halloween trick from my server.

Answer (score 0):

After you created/changed your virtual host file (1-/var/www/dev.example.com), did you restarted apache2 so those changes could take effect?

One way to do so (in case you didn't), is running this at your server's terminal:

`$ sudo systemctl restart apache2`

or

`$ sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Yes I did it was the first thing I did.